# Modern equivalent to Foxpro, Access, etc.?

Tags: windows, database

Is there a modern day equivalent to Foxpro, Access, and so on?

I'm looking for a programming environment that has database access built in as one of its most fundamental features. Something where the table data can be very easily tied into the GUI without having to write loads of glue code.

Also preferably one that compiles down to an EXE for distribution rather than having to bundle the environment itself.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Access was in the last Office release - so it is modern isn't it? .Net apps can be written wthout much code

Comment: Yes but doesn't Access still uses that file based database format that is easily corrupted when sitting on a file share and multiple users accessing it. Maybe I am wrong. But I am looking for something more robust...

Comment: VFP 9 SP2 was released 2 years ago...  While not bleeding edge modern, its release date was very close to Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find that most people consider that the "all-in-one" options cannot, by definition, be "modern".  That's because they use file-server database engines rather than client-server ones (if they used client-server engines, the database and user front-end would, by necessity, be separate processes).

I spend most of my time using file-server databases and find that they work great for the companies I work with.  But most people do not consider this kind of technology, which has limited scalability and is subject to file corruption problems if there are network issues, to be very up-to-date.

There are some development environments (my favorite is Delphi, but VS .NET is also in this category) which claim to provide the same development productivity that the all-in-one products do, but I don't find this to be the case.  I would love to see a product that "binds" to different database backends and provide the kind of productivity you get from Access, for instance, but if it exists I haven't heard about it.

Access is still being developed and supported, and I believe there's a current version of FoxPro as well.  I also spend a lot of time with a niche product, R:Base, which I find to be highly productive and to produce good-looking applications, but there are certainly trade-offs in terms of the programming language and access to the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

Servoy is seems to be a popular alternative for FoxPro developers. It contains a lot of the things you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of "*black* is the new black", I'm going to suggest Access.  It's still around, and it still does exactly what you need.

Comment: Doesn't the end user also need a copy of Access to run database programs made by this? That and the iffy multiple user support on databases makes me wary of Access. I will try it though thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Oliver: yeah, the end user does need Access to run it. Sorry, didn't notice that part.

Answer (score 0):

[Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is an excellent solution.

It has cross platform compliance. Adapters for .NET, Java, etc.

For front-end management of Sqlite databases, [see here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools).

Comment: Sqlite is only a backend - Access and Foxpro allow you to build a complete application

Comment: There are solutions to manage sqlite databases. [See here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools).
As for performance and ease of development, i still believe it is superior for using Access.

Comment: Thanks but that's not really the type of thing I'm looking for

Comment: OK, btw, this compiles down to a single DLL you attach to your distribution.

Comment: SQLite is the exact opposite of what Oliver was asking about.  It does not have any bound front end development environment at all.

Comment: PS: And I like SQLite as an embedded database.  But a development environment it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use [Delphi](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi) for development tools, [Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) for the database a database and [IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.com) for the IDE of the database